# no main-page.xml, other errors

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

Running on mac os, High Sierra, xode correctly installed and certificates issued.

> tns run ios

produces the following and does not generate a main-page.xml file -- why?

Note - simulator does launch and displays a blank iphone - if I manually create a main-page.xml file it runs but doesn't load the 'may app' apple image as suggested. Any help with the errors below and other would be appreciate as I'm stuck. Thanks.

> Building project…
>
> Xcode build…
>
> === BUILD TARGET HellowWorld OF PROJECT HellowWorld WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the
>   module cache was not found. Redistributable static libraries should
>   never be built with module debugging enabled. The debug experience
>   will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX5/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/Darwin-38I6DLZ5IH61J.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/Dispatch-2LX9MWM6UEPQW.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/9G23JDZCI6P8/ObjectiveC-1R06XOY9T4FIM.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Y0LVQ9G7OBT/UIKit-1V5UHAPTOD24G.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the
>   module cache was not found. Redistributable static libraries should
>   never be built with module debugging enabled. The debug experience
>   will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Y0LVQ9G7OBT/Darwin-38I6DLZ5IH61J.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Y0LVQ9G7OBT/Foundation-3DFYNEBRQSXST.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Y0LVQ9G7OBT/Dispatch-2LX9MWM6UEPQW.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> while processing
>   /Users/XXX/temp/NATIVE/HellowWorld/platforms/ios/internal/TKLiveSync/TKLiveSync(TKLiveSync.o):
>
> warning:
>   /Users/nsbuilduser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Y0LVQ9G7OBT/ObjectiveC-1R06XOY9T4FIM.pcm:
>   No such file or directory
>
> Project successfully built.
>
> Installing…
>
> Successfully installed on device with identifier
>   ‘02A10B95-DB8D-4C7B-8220-839642BCB7C2’.
>
> Successfully transferred all files.
>
> Refreshing application…
>
> Successfully synced application org.nativescript.HellowWorld on device
>   02A10B95-DB8D-4C7B-8220-839642BCB7C2

.

Comment: These warnings are not related to why your porject is not running. Post a link to the sample application you are trying to run or the code involved in the execution of your main-page

Comment: Well, these are related to Live Sync and live sync is not working. If I try to update files -- from either the nativescript or nativescript+angular tutorials NOTHING works. So, how do I get live sync to work?